# MVC Rotas Customizadas e Amigáveis | Criar uma Rota somente com um parâmetro na URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Como criar uma rota onde apenas ficaria exibido o parâmetro único?

Por exemplo, minha rota está atualmente assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "RouteEvent",
   url: "{ProdutoNome}",
   defaults: new { 
       controller = "Produto",
       action = "Detalhe", 
       ProdutoNome= UrlParameter.Optional 
});
```

e neste cenário quero que a `URL` visível no navegador seja apenas assim:

> URL: `localhost:43760/NomeDoMeuProduto`

porém, da forma que está, meu retorno está como `404` quando tento chamar esta `URL`.

Comment: É porque você já registrou uma rota que dá `match` nessa URL, a rota padrão do MVC vai capturar isso aí e tentar encontrar um controller cujo nome seja **`NomeDoMeuProduto`**

Comment: Creio que não. Pois no meu arquivo de rotas só está sendo registrada esta rota.

Comment: Não existe nem o registro padrão?

Comment: Neste caso eu retirei para testar. Mas sim, existirá sim.

Comment: Poste o arquivo de rotas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ordem em que as rotas são declaradas faz diferença. Existe a possibilidade de uma URL *bater* com duas rotas, mas o *router* vai comparar com as rotas na ordem que elas foram declaradas. A primeira que *bater* vence.

O correto é colocar **rotas específicas** no começo, pois caso elas não sejam adequadas, aí será analisada a rota *Default*. Poderíamos começar assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RouteEvent",
    url: "{ProdutoNome}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Produto",
        action = "Detalhe",
        ProdutoNome = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Primeiro vamos entender que TUDO o que vem depois do domínio e da porta (ex: depois de localhost:43760/), ou seja, todo o **caminho da URL** vem em forma de parâmetro para o `RouteValueDictionary`, inclusive o nome do Controller, da Action (e da Area se tivesse alguma), bem como os parâmetros propriamente ditos da action.

Até "funcionaria", mas não como gostaríamos. O problema é que todas as URLs com apenas um parâmetro (ou nenhum) iriam cair na primeira rota:

> localhost:43760 (sem parâmetros)
>
> localhost:43760/NomeDoMeuProduto (com um parâmetro *NomeDoMeuProduto*)
>
> localhost:43760/Home (com um parâmetro *Home*)
>
> localhost:43760/Account (com um parâmetro *Account*)

...pois a primeira rota é composta de **um único parâmetro** `ProdutoNome`, que ainda por cima é opcional.

Essas URLs não cairiam nela, no entanto:

> localhost:43760/Home/Index (dois parâmetros, Home e Index)
>
> localhost:43760/Account/Login (dois parâmetros, Account e Login)

Pois a rota **RouteEvent** espera apenas um parâmetro (`ProdutoNome` que até pode ser omitido), mas não dois parâmetros (ex: Home + Index ou Account + Login).

Ao remover o `ProdutoNome = UrlParameter.Optional`, pelo menos o `localhost:43760` já não cai mais nessa rota (pois o `ProdutoNome` é obrigatório). Ainda assim, todas as demais URLs com um único parâmetro (ex: apenas o Controller, omitindo a Action) cairiam naquela rota.

---

### Solução

Para resolver isso, temos que criar uma *Constraint* na rota específica, para verificar as URLs com um único parâmetro, e descobrir se esse parâmetro é de fato um Produto ou um Controller. Exemplo:

```
public class ProdutoConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        string nomeProduto = values[parameterName].ToString();
        using (var ctx = new MeuDbContext())
            return ctx.Produtos.Any(p => p.Nome == nomeProduto);
    }
}
```

...ou qualquer outra forma de você garantir que o valor em questão é um produto.

Você também poderia fazer o inverso, caso quisesse evitar um `SELECT` no banco. Poderia garantir que o parâmetro recebido não corresponde ao nome de nenhum Controller (talvez seja até melhor assim):

```
public class ProdutoConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
       return !Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MvcApplication))
            .GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .Any(c => c.Name.Replace("Controller", "") == values[parameterName].ToString());
    }
}
```

Assim tua rota ficaria dessa forma:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "RouteEvent",
    url: "{ProdutoNome}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Produto",
        action = "Detalhe"
    },
    constraints: new { ProdutoNome = new ProdutoConstraint() }
);
```

Obs: Se calhar de você ter um Controller cujo nome seja também o nome de um produto, obviamente teu Controller será ignorado, pois ele entenderá que você quer ver o produto, uma vez que ele existe. Mas seria o inverso se tua rotina estivesse tentando garantir que o parâmetro não fosse um Controller existente, nesse caso seria exibido o Controller ao invés do produto.

Lembrando que a `RouteEvent` deve ser declarada no `RouteConfig.cs` acima da rota `Default`.

Comment: Mandou bem Alisson. Vlw Acertou em cheio o que eu precisava.

Comment: @BrunoHeringer editei a resposta, coloquei uma solução alternativa que ao invés de ir no banco ver se o produto existe, faz o inverso, ou seja, verifica se o parâmetro recebido corresponde ao nome de algum Controller. Assim, se um usuário acessar um produto que foi excluído ou mesmo que não existe, ainda assim ele cairá na sua action Detalhes e você pode mostrar uma página informando que o produto "x" não foi localizado.

Comment: Top... Já estava fazendo o mesmo pra ficar top

Comment: atualizei sua resposta colocando o código que funcionou corretamente em Match. Se avaliar que seja melhor aceite a edição. De qualquer forma, reforço aqui... `return !Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MvcApplication))
                .GetTypes().Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
                .Any(c => c.Name.Replace("Controller", "") == values[parameterName].ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que você não tenha outro MapRoute, você fez uma controller chamado `ProdutoController` com uma action chamada `Detalhe`?, caso você não tenha feito o seu web server não vai achar essa rota e vai dar 404.

Você precisa de algo assim:

```
public class ProdutoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Detalhe(string produtoNome = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(produtoNome);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gabriel, Tenho uma Produto Controller e uma Action Detalhe. 
A questão é a rota mesmo: A chamada localhost:43760/NomeDoMeuProduto